# Передача в функцию переменные из массива циклом

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я пытаюсь рефакторить код. У меня есть одна функция которая часто дублируется и принимает несколько значений. Я создал цикл и не могу понять как мне преобразовать это в аргументы.

```
def mainFunc(x, x1, x2, x3 == 5):
    print('чето делаем')

def mainFuncMass(arr): 
    for attr in arr:
        #Если я буду передавать по ключу attr[0] attr[1] то если отсутствует ключ attr[3] 
        #выйдет ошибка. Это решается плохим кодом, чего мне делать не хочется.
        mainFunc(attr) # разное колво элементов

arr = [ [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 3, 4, 8], [0, 1, 2] ] 
mainFuncMass(arr)
```

Как мне грамотно решить данную задачу? Хотелось бы научится делать качественный, читаемый код.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно "развернуть" список/массив в набор значений с помощью знака `*`:

```
mainFunc(*attr)
```

Ну и, конечно, нужно исправить описание функции, значение по умолчанию задаётся через один знак `=`, а не через два. `==` - это сравнение:

```
def mainFunc(x, x1, x2, x3 = 5):
```